# Should I use was or were after multiple singular nouns?

Tags: grammar

> The computed minimum f0 (f0Min), maximum f0 (f0Max) and mean f0 (f0Mean) of each utterance (in Hertz) within all attitude types **was/were**(?) standardized as follows:...

There are three things before "was/were", but everyone is singular, so, should I use "was" or "were"?

Comment: You’ve got three subjects connected by *and*.

Comment: So you mean they have transformed into a singular?

Comment: Not so, it's rule #4 from [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

Comment: Alternatively you could structure the sentence "We standardize the computed minimum, maximum, and mean of each utterance as follows..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb is linked to the noun "**the computed X, Y and Z**" where all three can be looked **collectively**. Hence they are plural and **plural verb** will be used. i.e. "were"